# Nodejs request body items count

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I can't get the corret request body

here's my model schema

```
   name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    adresss:[{
        adresss:String,
     
        created_date:{ type: String, default: dateFormat(now, "dd/mm/yyyy")}
    },{
        usePushEach: true
    }]
```

Here what I'm sending and getting
[image]

```
var count = Object.keys(adresss).length
console.log('count'+count); // it gives 3 its fine but
```

When I send this

[image]

```
var count = Object.keys(adresss).length
console.log('count'+count); // it gives 4 which is character lenght, but I want 1, Because of this I can't update the array of addresses. How can I get this
```

How can I get element's count.It's not working when I send just 1 body

Comment: Anyone, It's not working for one arg

Comment: How can I update a subdocument array in mogoose